# CSS drop down menu keep constant background

Tags: html, css

I will include a screenshot at the bottom of what its supposed to look like and what it currently looks like as well as the jsfiddle.

I have at the moment got colors which are rather.. bold so i can see clearly what is what and i will change the colors when i have it right, I will post the relevent code in the jsfiddle.

- What its supposed to look like: http://tinypic.com/r/28s78tx/5
- What it looks like: http://tinypic.com/r/egw9pt/5
- jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CwCdF/

Im thinking a div which does something eh i dont really know :/ any ideas are welcome as well as a brief explanation, its no good just been spoon fed ;-) thanks loads.

Comment: Even with your fiddle and your pics, I still can't tell what you're trying to accomplish.  However, there are DOZENS of menu solutions out there that are already built and easily configured.  Perhaps you'd rather work with one of those?

Comment: *listens to the sound of tumble-weed rolling by*. How's about a response eh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how I would go about it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamessouth/J3BBe/).

It's **not** been tested cross browser as I haven't got the time nor has it been refactored to it's most efficient form.

I have though annotated the css so that you can figure out what is going on and I would do your best to analyse each part. If you still need me to explain anything, hopefully I should be able to.